# Cabal project: show full path to files

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I'm using cabal 3.2.0.0. I've created a `cabal.project` file which points to many submodules. When I run `cabal build all` and there is an error in a submodule, the path to the file with an error is shown relative to the cabal file of the submodule. This is very inconvenient with vim's `:make`. Is there a way to turn the path to relative from `.project` file? Or at least into absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've not found found how to do it with cabal, but I wrote a small vim plugin that band-aid fixes this problem.
https://github.com/d86leader/vim-config/blob/ac1651544b5c61f3dfa4f19a00946efb49056793/autoload/hs_cabal.vim